# Snowflake fetch latest record from identical field

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to insert records with distinct DIGITALID which has the lastest SRC_CREATED. That is, if there are 4 identical digitalis but rest other fields are different I want only the latest records ie record with MAX(SRC_CREATED). How can the query be modified to fetch only the latest record In case of identical digitalid?

Scenario mentioned :

| DIGITALID | DATA_TYPE | SRC_CREATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | click | 2021-04-10 01:50:08.490 |
| 1 | click | 2021-03-10 02:221:05.115 |
| 2 | open | 2021-06-10 01:12:08.288 |
| 1 | click | 2021-08-10 01:50:08.490 |

Outcome required :

| DIGITALID | DATA_TYPE | SRC_CREATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | click | 2021-08-10 01:50:08.490 |
| 2 | open | 2021-06-10 01:12:08.288 |

Query to be edited :

```
INSERT INTO "${intgdatabase}"."${profileschema}".CUSTOMER_PROFILE_DETAILS
(
    ADDRESS ,
    AGE ,
    CHURN_RATE ,
    CITY ,
    CITY_HASHED ,
    CONVERSION_TIME ,
    COUNTRY ,
    COUNTRY_CODE_HASHED ,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH_DAY_HASHED ,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH_MONTH_HASHED ,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH_YEAR_HASHED ,
    EMAIL ,
    EMAIL_ADDRESS_HASHED ,
    FIRST_NAME ,
    FIRST_NAME_HASHED ,
    FIRST_NAME_INITIAL_HASHED ,
    GENDER ,
    GENDER_HASHED ,
    HUX_ID ,
    IDENTITY_RESOLUTION ,
    LAST_CLICK ,
    LAST_EMAIL_OPEN ,
    LAST_NAME ,
    LAST_NAME_HASHED ,
    LTV_PREDICTED ,
    MATCH_CONFIDENCE ,
    MOBILE_DEVICE_ID ,
    PHONE ,
    PHONE_NUMBER_DIGITS_ONLY_HASHED ,
    POSTAL_CODE_HASHED ,
    PREFERENCE_EMAIL ,
    PREFERENCE_PUSH ,
    PREFERENCE_SMS ,
    PREFERENCE_IN_APP ,
    PROPENSITY_TO_PURCHASE ,
    PROPENSITY_TO_UNSUBSCRIBE ,
    SINCE ,
    STATE ,
    STATE_OR_PROVINCE_HASHED ,
    ZIP
)
    SELECT CONCAT(NVL(ADD1,''),NVL(ADD2,'')) AS ADDRESS,
    NULL AS AGE,
    NULL AS CHURN_RATE,
    NVL(CITY,'') AS CITY,
    SHA2(NVL(CITY,'')) AS CITY_HASHED,
    NULL AS CONVERSION_TIME,
    'USA' AS COUNTRY,
    SHA2(NVL(CNTRYCODE,'')) AS COUNTRY_CODE_HASHED,
    NULL AS DATE_OF_BIRTH_DAY_HASHED,
    NULL AS DATE_OF_BIRTH_MONTH_HASHED,
    NULL AS DATE_OF_BIRTH_YEAR_HASHED,
    NVL(IDT.EMAIL,'') AS EMAIL,
    SHA2(NVL(IDT.EMAIL,'')) AS EMAIL_ADDRESS_HASHED,
    NVL(IDT.FNAME,'') AS FIRST_NAME,
    SHA2(NVL(IDT.FNAME,'')) AS FIRST_NAME_HASHED,
    NULL AS FIRST_NAME_INITIAL_HASHED,
    CASE
    WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='F' THEN 'Female'
    WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='M' THEN 'Male'
    WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='U' Then 'Other'
    ELSE ''
    END AS GENDER,
    SHA2(NVL(GENDER,'')) AS GENDER_HASHED,
    IDT.DIGITALID AS HUX_ID,
    NULL AS IDENTITY_RESOLUTION,
    C.CLICK AS LAST_CLICK,
    C.OPENS AS LAST_EMAIL_OPEN,
    NVL(IDT.LNAME,'') AS LAST_NAME,
    SHA2(NVL(IDT.LNAME,'')) AS LAST_NAME_HASHED,
    NULL AS LTV_PREDICTED,
    NULL AS MATCH_CONFIDENCE,
    NULL AS MOBILE_DEVICE_ID,
    EI.PHONE AS PHONE,
    SHA2(EI.PHONE) AS PHONE_NUMBER_DIGITS_ONLY_HASHED,
    SHA2(NVL(ZIP,'')) AS POSTAL_CODE_HASHED,
    NULL AS PREFERENCE_EMAIL,
    NULL AS PREFERENCE_IN_APP,
    NULL AS PREFERENCE_PUSH,
    NULL AS PREFERENCE_SMS,
    NULL AS PROPENSITY_TO_PURCHASE,
    NULL AS PROPENSITY_TO_UNSUBSCRIBE,
    IDT.SRC_CREATED AS SINCE,
    NVL(STATE,'') AS STATE,
    SHA2(NVL(STATE,'')) AS STATE_OR_PROVINCE_HASHED,
    NVL(ZIP,'') AS ZIP
FROM "${basedatabase}"."${baseschema}"."IDENTITY" IDT
LEFT JOIN "${basedatabase}"."${baseschema}"."EMAIL_INTERACTIONS" EI
ON IDT.DIGITALID = EI.DIGITALID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DIGITALID
      , MAX(CASE WHEN EVENT_TYPE = 'click' THEN SRC_CREATED ELSE NULL END) CLICK
      , MAX(CASE WHEN EVENT_TYPE = 'open' THEN SRC_CREATED ELSE NULL END) OPENS
    FROM "${basedatabase}"."${baseschema}"."EMAIL_INTERACTIONS"
    GROUP BY DIGITALID
) C ON IDT.DIGITALID = C.DIGITALID;
```